# BackBoneJS Which one is the best approach ? fetch+success or bind on chage

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, backbone.js

I have a Backbone app, I get data in BackBone View from back-end API, then call a function `render` to render the template with the data I got.

I would like to know which one is the best practice to fetch and render, and why ?

1- Use fetch and then call `render` on `success` :

```
define(
    ['models/object',
        'text!templates/home.html',
        'backbone'
    ],
    function(ObjectModel, HomeTemplate, Backbone) {
        var homeView = Backbone.View.extend({

            initialize: function(options) {
                var self = this;
                this.homeTemplate = _.template(HomeTemplate);

                this.object = new ObjectModel({
                    id: <ANY_ID>
                }); 

                this.object.fetch({
                    success: function() {
                        self.render(self.object);
                    }
                });

            },
            render: function(data) {
                this.$el.html(this.homeTemplate);
                console.log(data);
                return this;
            },

        });

        return homeView;

    });
```

2- Bind the `objects` to `render` when they change:

```
define(
    ['models/object',
        'text!templates/home.html',
        'backbone'
    ],
    function(ObjectModel, HomeTemplate, Backbone) {
        var homeView = Backbone.View.extend({
            initialize: function(options) {
                var self = this;
                this.homeTemplate = _.template(HomeTemplate);

                this.object = new ObjectModel({
                    id: <ANY_ID>
                });

                this.object.bind('change', this.render, this);
                this.object.fetch()

            },
            render: function(data) {
                this.$el.html(this.homeTemplate);
                console.log(data);
                return this;
            },

        });

        return homeView;

    });
```

Comment: This depends on your application. If you want the entire view to be updated on every small change to model then you want to bind to `change` (Which is probably very bad for performance), or similar thing with any other event depending on your application.  If you handle small DOM updates yourself and only want the initial view render, then you can render entire template only once after fetch. There is no real answer to your question based on this tiny example. It requires broader view of the application, content and data management of the view etc.

Comment: Can't you decide what is required by this view in your application? Why exactly are you asking this question?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, no I won't have tiny changes, I will only show the abjects in a table, then when clicking on a row, you will get redirected of that object's page. I aked this question, coz I am not expert in Front-end, and would like to follow best practices, especially when there are seveal approches leading to the "same" result.

Comment: Then you definitely don't want to bind to `change` event. If your view wants to fetch the data again and re-render due to some user actions later, then you can bind to `sync` event. If it just fetches data once and displays it -rendering after model/collection fetch is success is just fine.

Comment: Thank you @T J I did it that way.

Comment: Don't use `bind` or `on`, prefer `this.listenTo(this.object, 'sync', callback)`. You don't need `self` as `fetch` can have a `context` option for the callbacks.

Comment: Thank you for this answer !